External react libraries CSS styling not working with shadow dom
I am trying to make a chatbot with react js, vite and typescript. I am using shadow DOM to turn it into a reusable web component but the problem is, the external react library im using, react-chatbot-it, none of its styling is seeming to show up on the final build files, although my own styling shows up fine. Any changes i am making to the components in that library are also not showing up on my built files. when i am running this application in development, everything seems to be fine as well.Is there a work around? For context, this is how it looks in development:
development chatbot and this is how it looks after building: built chatbot.
From the picture above, you can tell that the entrance form where it tells the user to enter name and email are identical as this does not use the react-chatbot-kit styling but everything else that does use that libraries styling seems to have disappeared.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
